# Spark: Is it possible to load an RDD from multiple files in different formats?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, file-format

I have an heterogeneously-formatted input of files, batch mode.

I want to run a batch over a number of files. These files are of different formats, and they will have different mappings to normalize data (e.g. extract fields with different schema names or positions in the records, to a standard naming).

Given the tabular nature of the data, I'm considering using Dataframes (cannot use datasets due to the Spark version I'm bound to).

In order to apply different extraction logic to each file - do they need to be loaded each file in a separate dataframe, then apply extraction logic (extraction of some files, a process which is different per each file type, configured in terms of e.g. CSV/JSON/XML, position of fields to select (CSV), name of field to select (JSON), etc.), and then join datasets? 
That would force me to iterate files, and act on each dataframe separately, and join dataframes afterwards; instead of applying the same (configurable) logic.

I know I could make it with RDD, i.e. loading all files into the RDD, emitting PairRDD[fileId, record], and then run a map where you would look the fileId to get the configuration to apply to that record, which tells you which logic to apply.

I'd rather use Dataframes, for all of the niceties it offers over raw RDDS, in terms of performance, simplicity and parsing.

Is there a better way to use Dataframes to address this problem than the one already explained? Any suggestions or misconceptions I may have?

I'm using Scala, though it should not matter to this problem.

Comment: why don't you separate parsing logic and transformation logic. create separate dataframe for each type and apply union over them and then you can run your transformation logic over this combined dataframe. There will be no performance overhead in this case.

Comment: I agree where possible :) 
But, once I create separate dataframes, I have each dataframe with a different columnar schema, so I guess that joining them would lead to a non-uniform structure, since values that _mean_ the same won't be understood as such (i.e. won't be under the same column, but different ones depending on the name of the field). Right?

Comment: well you can apply transformations and bring them to common schema.

Comment: Yes I could do that - transform the Dataframes separately and once they have the same schema, join them. But then, I'd not be parallelising as much, since transformations would occur on each separate dataframe, instead of doing them in one. 
Also, since each key for each file on the final reduction phase will be per-file (records on a file will have the same key, different from the next file's records) I think it wouldn't add much to the table.